# Create XPath filtering on type value?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have the below XML (that is part of a larger document):

```
 <class type="I want to filter on whatever value this is">
    <instance name="QuestionSet4">
      <property name="QuestionSetName">QuestionSet4</property>
      <property name="Ratio">5</property>
    </instance>
    <instance name="QuestionSetTrust">
      <property name="QuestionSetName">QuestionSetTrust</property>
      <property name="Ratio">5</property>
    </instance>
  </class>
```

My goal is to use PowerShell's `Select-Xml` such that I can return both of the `name` properties for each node using an XPath that filters on the class `type`, so that the output is something like this:

```
QuestionSetName, Ratio
QuestionSet4, 5
QuestionSetTrust, 5
```

The class `type` is unique in the document so I wondered if it was possible to filter based on that rather than hard coding the element like below:

```
/root/class[3]/@type
```

It would instead be `/root/class/@type="I want to filter on whatever value this is"...`

Instance names will change from document to document so I cannot filter on this either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve the relevant `instance` nodes with an XPath expression like the following:

```xml
//class[@type = 'I want to filter on whatever value this is']/instance
```

So you could construct the desired output objects like this:

```
$xml |Select-Xml -XPath "//class[@type = 'I want to filter on whatever value this is']/instance" |ForEach-Object { 
  [pscustomobject]@{
    QuestionSetName = ($_.Node |Select-Xml "./property[@name='QuestionSetName']").Node.InnerText
    Ratio           = ($_.Node |Select-Xml "./property[@name='Ratio']").Node.InnerText
  }
}
```

If you have a lot of `<property />` elements to enumerate for every `<instance />` it'll quickly get messy, but you can simplify it slightly like this:

```
$propertyNames = 'QuestionSetName','Ratio','Size','SomeOtherProperty'

$xml |Select-Xml -XPath "//class[@type = 'I want to filter on whatever value this is']/instance" |ForEach-Object { 
  $properties = [ordered]@{}
  foreach($name in $propertyNames){
    $properties[$name] = ($_.Node |Select-Xml "./property[@name='${name}']").Node.InnerText
  }

  [pscustomobject]$properties
}
```

Comment: Your first excerpt works perfectly. Thank you!